# Fish shell on windows outputs question mark before each prompt

Tags: windows, shell, intellij-idea, fish

I just switched to a windows machine and I'm trying to get fish configured correctly. I installed it through the default route, as a shell selected through cygwin setup. It seems to be working fine, but when I directly access fish.exe or run fish.exe through IntelliJ, it outputs a ? before very prompt:

[image: fish shell with question marks]

I googled and found this on [fish documentation FAQ](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html#faq-titlebar):

> **I'm seeing weird output before each prompt when using screen. What's wrong?**
>
> Quick answer:
>
> Run the following command in fish:
>
> echo 'function fish_title;end' > ~/.config/fish/config.fish
>
> Problem solved!
>
> The long answer:
>
> Fish is trying to set the titlebar message of your terminal. While
>   screen itself supports this feature, your terminal does not.
>   Unfortunately, when the underlying terminal doesn't support setting
>   the titlebar, screen simply passes through the escape codes and text
>   to the underlying terminal instead of ignoring them. It is impossible
>   detect and resolve this problem from inside fish since fish has no way
>   of knowing what the underlying terminal type is. For now, the only way
>   to fix this is to unset the titlebar message, as suggested above.
>
> Note that fish has a default titlebar message, which will be used if
>   the fish_title function is undefined. So simply unsetting the
>   fish_title function will not work

So it appears that intelliJ and cmd (fish.exe runs in cmd.exe if you access it directly) do not support setting the title bar, so they just output the character to the terminal instead. However, their suggested solution does not work. I've tried various options like echoing an empty string or a space, but nothing gets rid of that darn question mark.

Has anyone else run into this and found a solution?

---

Notes:

- It doesn't have this behavior when using fish through mintty.exe,
  most likely since that terminal supports setting the title, but I really prefer
  to use the terminal inside intelliJ instead of having it in a
  separate window.
- It didn't have this problem when I used fish through IntelliJ on Ubuntu or MacOSX, it appears to be isolated to Windows

Comment: What's the value of `$TERM` in that terminal? Is it different from mintty's `$TERM`?

Comment: In IntelliJ it's "xterm-256color", in mintty it's just "xterm", when I run fish.exe directly it's "cygwin"

Comment: Opened an issue on their github: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2092